# how to display the content of the state component in react

Tags: reactjs

i wrote an api to send the information in json form and i was able to store the data in state variable and if i try to display the content in JSX it just dose not work here is my code

```
import React , {Component, Fragment} from "react";
import Api from "../api"

const api = Api();

class Main extends Component {
   state = {
   data : []
}

componentDidMount(){
   api.get("/api/getallitems").then(
       response => {
           console.log(response.data)
           this.setState({
               data: response.data
           })
       }
    )
 }

render(){
    const {data} = this.state;
    return(
        <div>
        {
            data.length ?
            data.map(
            info => {
            <div>
                <h2 key={info.id}>{info.id, info.name, info.stock}</h2><br/>
                <script scr={console.log(info)}/>
            </div>
            }):null
         }
         this is data from api
         </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

[this is the output of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlvMc.png)

Comment: You're not returning anything inside the callback passed to `map`.

Comment: How to do that, its my first time with js, can you show a code snippet how to do it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you need to do it:

```
render(){
    const {data} = this.state;
    return(
        <div>
        {
            data.length ?
            data.map(
            info => {
    return(
            <div>
                <h2 key={info.id}>{info.id, info.name, info.stock}</h2><br/>
                <script scr={console.log(info)}/>
            </div>)
            }):null
         }
         this is data from api
         </div>
    );
  }
```